# Java- hot to have just 1 button to toggle back and forth instead of two buttons?

Tags: java, android, button

I have 1 button for changing an image and a text.
I wanted to make that same button so that if I click AGAIN, it would change back to the original image and the text. However, 'TextView' and 'ImageView' in Java code would tell me, I have already defined. Therefore, I guess I can't re-define them within 1 button.

I ended up creating 2 buttons: 1 to change and 2nd one to return back. How can I just have one button to change and return images and text? HELP!

```
    package com.example.android.cookies;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



/**
 * Called when the cookie should be eaten.
 */
public void eatCookie(View view) {
    // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) 
findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);

    // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    textView.setText("Im so full");
}

public void returnCookie(View view) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) 
findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.before_cookie);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    textView.setText("I'm so hungry");
}
}
```

[image: Before]

[image: ![after]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaSHV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a well maintained code for you. You can save current state. 
**I don't recommend `boolean`**. Because if you take `int` you can save more states in future, whereas in `boolean` you can save only two states- `true` or `false`.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;


    final int STATE_HUNGRY = 1;
    final int STATE_FULL = 2;
    int currentState = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (currentState) {
                    case STATE_FULL:
                        returnCookie();
                        break;
                    case STATE_HUNGRY:
                        eatCookie();
                        break;
                    default: // used when there is no state available
                        eatCookie();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void eatCookie() {
        currentState = STATE_FULL;
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
        textView.setText("Im so full");
    }

    public void returnCookie() {
        currentState = STATE_HUNGRY;
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.before_cookie);
        textView.setText("I'm so hungry");
    }
}
```

Comment: `I don't recommend boolean. Because if you take int you can save more states in future` - maybe an `enum` instead?

Comment: User who don't know to deal with button click. Should i tell Enum to him? Do you feel good to do this with him :)

Comment: Its up to you what you write, I'm simply telling you that an `enum` fits better.

Comment: You are right at your place. but let him take an start. He should understand basics first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a static variable to keep track of the currently displayed image? Static means it will maintain its state between function calls. Then toggle it each time the function is called. The initial declaration will only be called once.

```
static Boolean eaten = false;
```